# PHP Mailer Error: Mailer Error - must provide at least one recipient email address

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer

I'm having and an issue with php mailer script. Using mamp the script works, but on the server I get an error (I've omitted sensitive info).

> "Invalid address: [valid email] Mailer Error: You must
>   provide at least one recipient email address."

Heres my code:

```
require_once("includes/phpmailer/class.phpmailer.php");

    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP();

    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.emailsrvr.com"; 
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                    
    $mail->Port       = 25;                    
    $mail->Username   = "test@test.com"; 
    $mail->Password   = "test";

    $mail->Subject = "Subject";

    $mail->SetFrom($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);
    $mail->AddReplyTo($_POST['email'], $_POST['name']);

    $address = "test@test.com";
    $mail->AddAddress($address, "name");

    $body = "<p>test</p>";

    $mail->MsgHTML($body);


    if(!$mail->Send()) {
      echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
      echo "Message sent!";
    }
```

If it helps, I am using the rackspace email apps.

Im not very savy with php or server setups unfortunately so if anyone can help that would be great!

Comment: Which part of *"Invalid address: [valid email]"* is hard to understand? `[valid email]` is just not a valid email address. Use a valid one instead.

Comment: Hi hakre, by [valid email] i mean I have used a valid email in that variable. Sorry for the confusion, I've fixed up the post now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i had no luck here, but I now know the issue stems from server mail settings rather then the script.

In the end I just went to using postmark.

Answer (score 2):

Just change this line:

```
$address = "[valid email]";
```

to something like:

```
$address = "test@test.te";
```

or to your own email, so you can test better, and it will work.

It's just stating that '[valid email]' is not actually a "valid email".

Comment: Sorry to be confusing, by [valid email] I mean I have written in an  email that works for that variable. I just wrote [valid email] above to protect identity of the email. Even as "test@test.te" it still doesnt work. :(

Comment: You changed it in the message too, then?

Ok, then I'd try

     `$mail->AddAddress($address);`

To test the function

Answer (score 0):

I face this issue when my class name and my function name is same. Than i change the name of the function and it was resolved. Hope it will help anyone.